# How to rotate an embedded web map (on pc)?

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, vector-tiles

I was looking through a couple of maps I made, the maps were created by serving `VectorTiles` through [`TileStache`](http://tilestache.org/) and using [`Leaflet`](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson) and [`Tangram`](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram) (on respective pages) to render them. One of the reasons I wanted to use a Vector Tile map was because `Vector Tiles` are  [rendered on the client end](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/vector-tiles/) (as opposed to the per-rendered raster tiles we get) so the styling is applied by the client, which means that the labels and icons applied on them will not be static (they should realign when the map orientation is changed). I wanted to test this by changing my map orientation, and realized that I can't rotate my map on the pc. I looked into it and discovered that  [`Google Maps` can't be rotated as well](https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/36qlk0/how_do_i_rotate_google_maps_on_pc/).

Is there any way I can **rotate** the **maps** I have embedded? Is there a way to somehow change the orientation of `Google Maps` (or any embedded web map) on a PC?

***Update:*** So [OpenLayers 3](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.0/examples/rotation.html) supports rotation but I can't embed Tangram in OL3, is there a way to rotate a Leaflet map?

Comment: I think maps are rotateable in 'Android `

Comment: Yes, and I want to get the same functionality in PC.

Comment: Openlayers3 have provided support for webmap rotation.

Answer (score 4):

OpenLayers3 support map rotation. [Here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.0/examples/rotation.html) you can check an example.
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271504/rotate-openlayers3-map-via-javascript-onload-and-via-function) might be helpful for your  scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet does not support map rotation, and never will, as developers state [in this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/268). They recommend using other libraries for that, notably OpenLayers 3, Mapbox GL JS and Tangram.

But in 2016 Fabien and Ivan made an experimental branch with rotation, [archived here](https://github.com/va2ron1/Leaflet). It needs a `rotate: true` option for a `L.Map` object, and there is a `setBearing(degrees)` method.